# Amazon Chime SDK for ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk

I'm following the [documentation](https://aws.github.io/amazon-chime-sdk-component-library-react/?path=/story/introduction--page) to integrate the Amazon Chime into my Web App made with React but I got stuck at this part: `await fetch('/my-server');`.

I have created a Chime account and invited two users that could attend a test meeting, but I couldn't see any API Key or something related to that for integrations.

How do I set up a server to work with Chime? Can't I use something directly from Amazon just for testing purposes and work only with the Front End App?

Comment: I think you cannot join meeting created with chime web Application. You need to create the meeting by yourself using aws sdk api to createMeeting. Also in the await fetch('/server') you need to call the api and get the Meeting and Attendee Info. There are no proper implementation explained anywhere moreover the worst part is we cannot test it freely. We need an Aws Account and paid chime service even for testing. I think Amazon should look into this.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks for the info!